# How can I trace a 500 Internal server error that only appears outside the server?

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-5

When I'm at a client computer and send a request to a server to change a field with a script of an ad in it, I'm denied to save the script but when I'm trying to save another type of content I'm allowed to.
But while I'm at the server with the same account I can save the script with no problem.
At the same time this website has a development server and in this server I can make the changes without any trouble.
How can I search where the problem is to fix it?

Comment: I found the problem, what my problem was it's that I totally forgot to declare tell the controller it was going to recept html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was that I forgot to tell the controller not to validate the value it was reciving, since the error description was not actually telling me what the problem was, I had a little trouble finding the answer.